# Bounding the summation of the degrees of the endpoints of all edges in an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose that $G=(V,E)$ is an undirected simple graph with $n=|V|$ vertices and $m=|E|$ edges. Then, I need to bound the following quantity while measuring the running-time of an algorithm which computes the symmetric-difference between neighbors of vertices $u$ and $v$ for each edge $\{u,v\}\in E$:
$$A=\sum_{\{u,v\}\in E}\left(d(u)+d(v)\right),$$
where $d(v)$ equals to the degree of vertex $v$ in the graph $G$.

My tries are as follows:

- Given that $d(u)\leq \Delta(G)$, where $\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree of the graph, this quantity can be bounded by $\mathcal{O}\left(m\times \Delta(G)\right)$
- Given that $d(u) \leq n-1$, this quantity can be bounded by $\mathcal{O}(mn)$.

The first upper-bound is much tighter than the second, but I wonder if I can do any better.

Answer (score 2):

Each node $i$ appears exactly $d_i$ times in the sum, so $A=\sum_{i\in V} d_i^2$ and $A \le n \Delta^2$ is another upper bound.